# how to know how many bytes UTF-16 send to you

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-16, utf-32

UTF-16 can be two bytes character sets or four bytes character sets.

As I understand, the four byte character sets consist of surrogates which are high(16) and low(16).

I know that UTF-8 can be either one, two, three, four, or up to seven bytes.

But we can tell how many bytes are coming from UTF-8 easily by looking at the bits in the first octet.

I wonder how we identify the bytes size coming from UTF-16 plus UTF-32.

I would appreciate your help and welcome opinions on Unicode.

Comment: What is "UTF-16 plus UTF-32"?

Answer (score 4):

### **UTF-8**

This uses *1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes* per codepoint, depending on the codepoint's value (5+ byte variations are not allowed by [RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629) in order to maintain compatibility with UTF-16, as they can encode codepoints higher than UTF-16's max codepoint of U+10FFFF).  Analyzing the **high bits of the first byte** will tell you how many total bytes are in the sequence, including that first byte:

1. if the high bit is 0, the byte's numeric value is the codepoint's value.
2. if the high 2 bits are 1 and the high 3rd bit is 0, the codepoint value spans 2 bytes. The next byte must have its high bit set to 1 and its high 2nd bit set to 0, or else the sequence is malformed.
3. if the high 3 bits are 1 and the high 4th bit is 0, the codepoint value spans 3 bytes. The next 2 bytes must have their high bit set to 1 and their high 2nd bit set to 0, or else the sequence is malformed.
4. if the high 4 bits are 1 and the high 5th bit is 0, the codepoint value spans 4 bytes. The next 3 bytes must have their high bit set to 1 and their high 2nd bit set to 0, or else the sequence is malformed.
5. if 5 or more high bits are set to 1, the sequence is malformed.

---

### **UTF-16**

This uses *2 or 4 bytes* per codepoint, depending on the codepoint's value.  Analyzing the **numeric value of the first 2 bytes** (taking big/little endian into account) will tell you how many total bytes are in the sequence, including those first 2 bytes.

1. If the numeric value is in the range of 0x0000..0xD7FF or 0xE000..0xFFFF, it is the codepoint value.
2. If the numeric value is in the range of 0xD800..0xDBFF, the codepoint value spans 4 bytes.  The first 2 bytes are the high surrogate. The numeric value of the next 2 bytes must be in the range of 0xDC00..0xDFFF for the low surrogate, or else the sequence is malformed.
3. If the numeric value is in the range of 0xDC00..0xDFFF, the sequence is malformed.

---

### **UTF-32**

This is always *4 bytes* per codepoint.  The numeric value of the 4 bytes (taking big/little endian into account) is the codepoint value.